# counting symmetric nilpotent matrices

Tags: matrices, finite-fields

In a recent paper [ Counting symmetric nilpotent matrices , by A. Brouwer],

the author states that the number of  3x3  symmetric  nilpotent

matrices over the field of  q  elements is given by the formula:

```
     q^3  +  q^2  - q
```

In the case of characteristic  2  , the situation simplifies a

little and one can readily prove the formula.

Question: Is there a straightforward proof in the case of

odd characteristic?